# CAN'T UPGRADE FROM WINDOWS 8 TO WINDOWS 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, upgrade, windows-10-upgrade

I have a Lenovo laptop that is currently running Windows 8, and it is not a bad laptop:

[image]

When I try to run the Windows 10 setup I get this error when it's almost done:

[image]

I am using the 21H1 update installer.

I do not wanna format the PC because I do not have my Windows activation key, so I wanna use the one that Windows is using currently.

Comment: After the process, you should have a new folder, something like C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\ or C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources\Panther or something. This folder is used for the upgrade process. It will contain a log file that tells you why the upgrade fails. Its usually some software or driver that causes havoc, such as a virusscanner with tamper protection.

Comment: No, i don't. The only folders that start with a dollar and are at C: are: `$WINDOWS.~BT` and `$Windows.~WS`.

Comment: Yes, and inside these folders, you have Sources, Panther with logfiles. These are the folders that are used. Somewhere in there, you will find log files

Comment: This is the message that I got in the log file: `Error MOUPG CDlpTask::Cancel(982): result = 0xC1800104`

Comment: Good, now google what it means, and you'll find the solution, or it will redirect you to what to check also. This will lead you to: "Error Code 0xC1900208 means MOSETUP_E_COMPAT_INSTALLREQ_BLOCK - Setup found an actionable compat issue, such as an incompatible app or driver.
Please check the CompatData files in the folder C:\$WINDOWS. ~ BT\Sources\Panther on Upgrade Blocker Information."

Comment: "I do not have my Windows activation key" - You don't need one.  Windows 10 will automatically detect the license key stored on your machine and automatically activate. `Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder` won't display your actual license key by the way.  In my opinion it's unnecessary software.  If you really want software that will display the key you should instead use [Show Key Plus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases).  However, I will repeat, knowing your license key is unnecessary when you are trying to install any modern supported version of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound "Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder won't display your actual license key"? Why not? Then what does it show?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder to find your key https://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/

Then use the following procedure to update to Windows 10. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d